# Not able to work with tables created with Flyway in H2 database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2, flyway

I am new to flyway and struggling a bit to create tables using flyway in H2 database

I have created tables in my oracle Database using flyway script.

Now I want to perform some Junit test and want to create tables using Flyway script but not in 
oracle Database instead I want to create this in H2 database (For unit test).

Flyway script used in my case is different both script have slightly different table structure.

Below is my project structure and configuration used

[image: Project Structure]

Below is the configuration present in **src/main/resources** folder

**V1.0.0.0.001__tables.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE COMMAND_ACTION 
(COMMAND_TYPE_CD VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
ACTION VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
ACTION_ORDER NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT COMMAND_ACTION_PK PRIMARY KEY (COMMAND_TYPE_CD, ACTION_ORDER),
CONSTRAINT COMMAND_ACTION_FK FOREIGN KEY (ACTION) REFERENCES ACTION_DEFINITION(ACTION)
);

CREATE TABLE COMMAND_ACTION_CONFIGURATION 
(   COMMAND_TYPE_CD VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
ACTION VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
CONFIGURATION VARCHAR2(1024 BYTE) NOT NULL);
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=cca
spring.flyway.table=CCA_SCHEMA_VERSION
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
spring.flyway.schemas=CCA
spring.flyway.user=cca
spring.flyway.password=cca
```

**application-cca.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@linux:8080:devdb
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@linux:8080:devdb
spring.datasource.username=cca
spring.datasource.password=cca
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Below is the configuration present in **src/test/resources** folder

**V1.0.0.0.001__tables.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE COMMAND_ACTION 
(COMMAND_TYPE_CD VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
ACTION VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
ACTION_ORDER NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT COMMAND_ACTION_PK PRIMARY KEY (COMMAND_TYPE_CD, ACTION_ORDER),
CONSTRAINT COMMAND_ACTION_FK FOREIGN KEY (ACTION) REFERENCES ACTION_DEFINITION(ACTION)
);

CREATE TABLE COMMAND_ACTION_CONFIGURATION 
(   COMMAND_TYPE_CD VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
ACTION VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
CONFIGURATION VARCHAR2(1024 BYTE) NOT NULL);
```

**test.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=test
spring.flyway.table=CCA_SCHEMA_VERSION
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
spring.flyway.user=
spring.flyway.password=
```

**application-test.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:DATABASE
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:h2:mem:DATABASE
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.database.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
# Enabling H2 Console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

I want that my junit should work independent of my src/resources but not able to achieve instead getting 
below error whenever I run maven install

```
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_66]
2020-02-27T12:45:22,000 DEBUG  CommandService                 [pool-3-thread-1] Timer is started.
2020-02-27T12:45:22,001 ERROR  CommandService                 [pool-3-thread-1] Error in processing command. Error :{}
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "COMMAND_ACTION" not found; SQL statement:
select ca.command_type_cd,  ca.action, cac.CONFIGURATION from command_action ca
left outer join command_action_configuration cac 
on ca.command_type_cd = cac.command_type_cd  and ca.action = cac.action
order by ca.command_type_cd, ca.action_order [42102-200]
```

Either some time I get checksum related error.

Comment: Why `test.properties`? Those aren't loaded by default and have you properly enabled the `test` profile on your tests.

Comment: Hello @M.Deinum yes I have provided profile properly property source above my test class as @TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")

Comment: Use `@ActiveProfiles("test")` instead. The `application.properties` is read earlier I suspect.

Comment: So I have provided @ActiveProfiles("test") at root class ie, ApplicationTests and I can see below log
earlier I only had cca , but i understand that we only need test here to be in active state but cca is also coming.

2020-02-27T13:16:46,804 INFO  ApplicationTests [main      ] The following profiles are active: test,cca

Comment: Because that is in your `application.properties`. IMHO you shouldn't place those things in your `application.properties` but only supply them externally. If they are on by dfeault just put those in `applicaiton.properties` instead of magically enabling a profile.

Comment: Actually  I will need application.properties for the values that will never change and application-cca.properties values can be changed so I will have application-cca.properties always. :(

Comment: Why? You can just put everything in `application.properties` and the ones from the profile will override the other ones.